# one script in all my HTML files that dynamically goes to the next/previous HTML page in the same folder

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, perl, jquery-ui

Hi I have 2000 html files in one folder and their names follow upon each other like this:

01_001.html
01_002.html
01_003.html
01_004.html
02_001.html
02_002.html
02_003.html
..............
33_001.html
33_002.html
33_003.html
..............
33_123.html

I would like to add add a link/script to all 2000 HTML files that will dynamically go to the next/previous HTML page in the same folder

I know how to add this in PERL, but what should that kind of link/script look like in JavaScript/jQuery

I have tried this script:

```
<a href="#" onClick="movePrv();">Previous</a> end <a href="#" onClick="moveNext();">Next</a>
```

But it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Javascript can't see the filesystem, so won't know when to change from 01_004 to 02_001.

Comment: No offence, but what could possibly warrant such a terrible mess of files? I think whatever you're doing, you *really* should be considering what other options are available to you.

Comment: Adam lets say we leave the option to go from 01_004 to 02_001 is there a way to go from 01_004 to 01_003 or 02_004 to 02_005? No offense taken it is a book with many chapters and [01]_001 is the chapter and 01_[001] categories in each chapter. I usually use PHP, so just for interest is there a way to do this with PHP script in each file.  I can change the files to *.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution in PHP might look like this:

```
<?php
$file = basename(__FILE__);
$chap = substr($file, 0, 2);
$cat = substr($file, 3, 3);
$prevFile = sprintf("%1$02d_%2$03d.php", $chap, ($cat-1));
$nextFile = sprintf("%1$02d_%2$03d.php", $chap, ($cat+1));
echo($prevFile);
echo($nextFile);

$isFirst = ($cat == "000");
$isLast = !file_exists($nextFile);
?>
```

Use the variables `$nextFile` and `$prevFile` to create Links. You might also want to check whether the current file is the first or last in a chapter and then not to show a previous or next link.

Comment: I have one more question, you said I may need to check whether the current file is the first or last in a chapter. How will I do this?

Comment: I can get that the first one does not show prevFile like this 

`<?php
$file = basename(__FILE__);
$a = substr($file, 0, 2);
$b = substr($file, 3, 3);
$bp = ($b-1);
$prevFile = sprintf("%1$02d_%2$03d.php", $a, ($b-1));
$nextFile = sprintf("%1$02d_%2$03d.php", $a, ($b+1));
if ( $bp == 000 ){
 $prevFile = "";
}
echo($prevFile);
echo($nextFile);
?>' 

any ideas how I can get the last file not to show nextFile seeing that the amount of categories per chapters are not the same

Comment: Well, the first file will have `$cat == "000"`. You could check for the last file with `file_exists($nextFile)`. Remember tough, that while this is an easy solution, it is not a very elegant one.

Comment: Glad to hear! If your problem is solved, consider marking the most helpful answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that using the default Perl sort brings the file names into the correct order, it certainly suffices for the provided example data. If not, have a look at [Sort::Naturally](http://p3rl.org/Sort%3a%3aNaturally) instead.

I assume that each file contains the character sequence `</head`, signifying the end of the HTML header. I insert the [link relations](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.1.2) just before. For highly irregular mark-up, a HTML parser such as [Web::Query](http://p3rl.org/Web%3a%3aQuery) is required.

The code will link all files in a ring/Ouroboros fashion. The array index `-1` [DTRT](http://catb.org/jargon/html/D/DWIM.html) and refers to the last array element.

Code untested:

```
use 5.012;  # for "each @array"
use File::Slurp qw(read_file write_file);

my @order = sort qw(
    01_001.html
    01_002.html
    01_003.html
    01_004.html
    02_001.html
    02_002.html
    02_003.html
    33_001.html
    33_002.html
    33_003.html
    33_123.html
);
while (my ($i, $curr_file) = each @order) {
    my $next_file = $order[$i + 1];
    my $prev_file = $order[$i - 1];
    my $content = read_file $curr_file, { binmode => ':raw' };
    $content =~ s
        {</head}
        {
            <link rel="next" href="$next_file">
            <link rel="prev" href="$prev_file">
            </head
        };
    write_file $curr_file, {binmode => ':raw'}, $content;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create some server side PERL script to return the next/previous file name. In Javascript you can use AJAX method to get the file next or previous file name, then redirect. I think that is the feasible and simplest option you have.